# difference between <xsl:apply-template> and <xsl:call-template>?

Tags: xml, xslt

would you please explain me the difference between`<xsl:apply-template>` and `<xsl:call-template>` and when should i use `<xsl:call-template>` ?
thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On a very basic level, you use `<xsl:apply-templates>` when you want to let the processor handle nodes automatically, and you use `<xsl:call-template/>` when you want finer control over the processing. So if you have:

```
<foo>
    <boo>World</boo>
    <bar>Hello</bar>
</foo>
```

And you have the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="boo">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

You will get the result `WorldHello`. Essentially, you've said "handle bar and boo this way" and then you've let the XSLT processor handle these nodes as it comes across them. In most cases, this is how you should do things in XSLT.

Sometimes, though, you want to do something fancier. In that case, you can create a special template that doesn't match any particular node. For example:

```
<xsl:template name="print-hello-world">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat( bar, ' ' , boo )" />
</xsl:template>
```

And you can then call this template while you're processing `<foo>` rather than automatically processing `foo`'s child nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:call-template name="print-hello-world"/>
</xsl:template>
```

In this particular artificial example, you now get "Hello World" because you've overriden the default processing to do your own thing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So far this is the best explanation I've ever read on xslt.(although I have to add that xslt is not my thing, and possibly never will be)

Answer (score 3):

> would you please explain me the difference between
>   `<xsl:apply-template>` and `<xsl:call-template>` and when should i use
>   `<xsl:call-template>` ?

**One *can* use `<xsl:call-template>` but almost *never* should**.

**It is in the spirit of XSLT to allow the XSLT processor** to determine exactly which template *best matches* a node and to decide to use this template for processing that node. This gives us clean, easy and powerful extensibility and polymorphism.

In general, comparing `xsl:apply-templates` to `xsl:call-template` is similar to comparing  the invoking of a virtual method from a base class to that of calling a non-virtual method directly.

**Here are some important differences**:

1. **`xsl:apply-templates` is much richer and deeper than `xsl:call-templates` and even from  `xsl:for-each`,** simply because we don't know what code will be applied on the nodes of
   the selection -- in the general case this code will be different for
   different nodes of the node-list.
2. **The code that will be applied
   can be written way after the `xsl:apply-templates` was written** and by
   people that do not know the original author.

**The [FXSL library](http://fxsl.sf.net)'s implementation of higher-order functions (HOF) in XSLT wouldn't be possible** if XSLT didn't have the `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction.

**Summary**: Templates and the `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction is how XSLT implements and deals with polymorphism. One can and should avoid using `xsl:call-template`, which doesn't allow polimorphism and limits reusability and flexibility.

**Reference**: See this whole thread: **http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200411/post60540.html**