# Repeatable, Parameterized for-each in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a parameterized, repeatable XML snippet that I refer to throughout an XSLT (2.0).  It takes a semi-colon delimited string, that I tokenize and loop over to produce each child element.  For example string `USNY;UKLN` would produce:

```
<businessCenters>
    <businessCenter>USNY</businessCenter>
    <businessCenter>UKLN</businessCenter>
</businessCenters>
```

It is straightforward to use a for-each in-place each time I wish to produce this, however I'd like to modularize this by having a function or similar.

Having had a Google, it strikes me that a function is the wrong way to do this because I'm not returning a value and simply wish to process the string in-place at the node point.  So a named template looks like perhaps the right way to do this, with a parameter passed in for the string. This [link](https://mukulgandhi.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/xslt-functions-returning-void.html) seems to suggest I'm on the right track.

```
<xsl:template name="business-centers">
    <xsl:param name="centers" as="xs:string"/>
    <businessCenters>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($centers,';')">
            <businessCenter>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </businessCenter>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </businessCenters>
</xsl:template>
```

Can be called like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="business-centers">
    <xsl:with-param name="centers" select="myns:get_centers($foo)"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

This seems to work.  However my question is - is this the right way to do this?

Am I right in assuming there isn't a sensile way to do this with a function?

Also am I right in assuming that although advice seems to be as a general rule to prefer apply-template, over call-template - there is no sensible way to do this here either (as per [difference between <xsl:apply-template> and <xsl:call-template>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443029/difference-between-xslapply-template-and-xslcall-template))?

**Update**

So following the advice below from @martin-honnen - it seems that rather than use the function as a side-effect to produce the XML, I can return the generated XML like so.  I hadn't appreciated that the (result of the) whole body of the function is returned - pretty neat.

Note I'm not specifying a return type?  Is this normal?

```
<xsl:function name="qt:business-centers">
    <xsl:param name="centers" as="xs:string"/>
    <businessCenters>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($centers,';')">
            <businessCenter>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </businessCenter>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </businessCenters>
</xsl:function>
```

In light of this I guess my only outstanding question is - am I right in assuming the use of the function or named template is nothing more than a person style question?  Or is there a technical reason to prefer one or the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to explain which document you found with Google and which passage of that document you interpret as you say, that a function does not work. If you stuff your code you have in that named template into a function and call that with e.g. `<xsl:sequence select="mf:business-centers(myns:get_centers($foo))"/>`, it, like the named template, returns a `businessCenters` element node. So that is perfectly fine as a function use.

As for using `apply-templates`, you can do that in XSLT 3  with e.g.

```
<businessCenters>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="tokenize($centers,';')"/>
</businessCenters>

<xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:string]" expand-text="yes">
  <businessCenter>{.}</businessCenter>
</xsl:template>
```

XSLT 2 doesn't allow you to write templates matching primitive values like strings.

Comment: Thanks.  I should rephrase, that it was an absence of advice on using functions this way (on Google), rather than a specific article criticizing there use?  I took your advice and simply leaving off the return type it works just as you say (I'll update my question shortly).

Comment: Named templates can have return types just like functions in XSLT 2 or 3 so you can type the function as `as="element(businessCenters)"` if you want to specify a type and you could do the same with the named template if needed/wanted. It is just that named templates existed in XSLT 1 without that feature and user-defined functions did not exist at all (unless using extension mechanisms).

Comment: So named templates are perfectly fine to use, but hark back to an earlier version of XSLT when the use of functions was impossible.  With XSLT 2.0 I can decide which I prefer, and the choice is pretty much down to personal taste (at least for this example) -  Is that the gist of it?

Comment: For that example, yes. But functions can be called in other expressions e.g. you can `<xsl:apply-templates select="mf:business-centers(myns:get_centers($foo))"/>` for instance to push the result computed in a function to another processing step. That is just an example, the main advantage is the general integration into anything that takes an XPath expression so you can use e.g. `<xsl:template match="foo[mf:my-function(.) = 'bar']">`, with named templates you would have a hard time using variables to store the result and use the variable then in XPath.

Comment: One issue exists as a difference, in XSLT 3 you can define whether a call to a function returns the same nodes in terms of node identity or new ones each time, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#function-determinism. I am not sure this is a refinement of some vagueness in the XSLT 2 spec or a new feature in XSLT 3.

Comment: One last thing on this - if I use a function the generated XML (as per my update in the question) has an empty namespace attribute `<businessCenters xmlns="">` - is there any way to supress that?

Comment: Is that in a single stylesheet with the same namespace declarations in scope for the `xsl:function` and the `xsl:template`? I can't really imagine why that would happen. Of course, whether you use a function or a template or a direct sequence constructor, if you create a result element in no namespace and copy it into a container element in a namespace then the serializer will add the `xmlns=""` to preserve the null namespace. So we really need to see some minimal but complete context to tell what happens. I am rather sure it is not related to using functions versus templates.

Comment: Yes! Thanks again - that was the clue I needed.  This is a single XSL file, but the namespace of the nested container is different from that of the functions which are defined at the top of the file.  By copying the xmlsns attribute of the parent to result element (`<businessCenters xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2">`) the XML forms correctly.  As you rightly said, you couldn't have known that without seeing the whole document.

Comment: If the stylesheet is only supposed to create result elements in one single namespace it is also possible to move the default namespace declaration `xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2"` directly on the `xsl:stylesheet` respectively `xsl:transform` root element, that way it is in scope for any result elements create in the stylesheet (unless of course you override it somewhere down the hierarchy).

Answer (score 1):

I often find it more convenient to use functions when the result is an atomic value, and named templates (or template rules) when the result is a node tree, but that's purely a convenience and a convention: both functions and templates can return any XDM value without restriction. The difference between functions and templates is how they are called, not what they can do.

Comment: I had arrived at a similar convention too - I think from using other languages it "feels" nicer for me to have functions returning atomic values, and templates producing chunks of XML.  But having discussed this now, it's call semantics and personal taste that dictates this.